# Monaca Visual Studio Extension disable cloud syncing

Tags: git, visual-studio, monaca

I am using Monaca to build an Android app, and am working with a development team. We are setting up the project with git for source control, but the problem is the Monaca plugin for Visual Studio auto syncs with the Monaca cloud. As you can imagine, this will create a mess as we are using git but each team member's local copy will automatically pull the latest version from Monaca and also push their changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.  Git for source control just makes sense for a lot of folks, so it'd be nice if we could choose whether to run in local kit mode vs cloud mode.